# Right click shortcut for Mac Lion OS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, right-click

How to perform right click through Keyboard in Mac Lion OS? Since I am keyboard loving person, I don't like all the time use mouse for right click. I found much of the shortcuts of Mac through googling, but I didn't found this one.

Comment: Ask this on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com/). I think this question is not for StackOverflow!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I got my answer:

Go to **System Preference -->  Universal Access  -->  Mouse --> Enable Mouse Keys (ON)**

This will Enable you Numpad keys. Press **Ctrl + 5** for Right Click.

Comment: and what if we do not have a numeric keyboard, as in a Macbookpro?

Comment: What's the point of using `C-5` if you *still* have to position the cursor? You just might right-click while you're at it.

Comment: This option would leave your keys useless and you wont be able to type anymore.

Comment: An answer was deleted on this page for being too similar to this accepted answer. However, it suggested that "Universal Access" is now called "Accessibility" - could someone confirm this, and if it is the case, make an edit to this answer? I wonder if the menu option was renamed in a later release of the software.

Answer (score 13):

Fn-Ctrl-I on laptop

thanks to this post:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2018015?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Doesn't work. Using Macbook Air (Mid-2013 Model) with OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: For Fn + Ctrl + I, you have to have mouse keys enabled first. But it only performs right click where the mouse is, not on the currently-selected item in say Finder, e.g.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in **MacOS Catalina** -
With every release, Apple is organizing all accessibility related controls under Accessibility in System Preferences. Steps to enable context menu (right click) with keyboard-

1. System Preferences --> Accessibility
2. Accessibility --> Pointer Control
3. Alternate Control Methods --> Enable alternate pointer control options
4. Select this checkbox to enable this option
5. Click on the options button next to this option --> Default for right click is **F12**

Comment: This is perfect for Catalina+. Zero dependencies and it works exactly as can expected.  Something to note is you can also map key combinations or other keys through this option.  Personally I have mapped option+enter

Answer (score 0):

If use is restricted to `Finder` only and you do not mind incurring monetary costs, I would suggest the combination of [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) and its workflow called [RightClick](https://github.com/vitorgalvao/alfred-workflows/tree/master/RightClick). It works on Catalina.