# Is it Possible to use AppleScript to access right click context?

Tags: shell, scripting, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, dropbox

I'd like to assign a right-click context to a keyboard shortcut using something like an AppleScript.

For example:

If I right click a folder in Dropbox it gives me a "Share Dropbox Link" menu. Is it possible to access this without using the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my script below for accessing the context menu, you'll need both MouseLocation, and cliclick that you'll find via Google.

You may want to edit it a little (and adjust the hardcoded paths to both MouseLocation, and cliclick), but it should really be no problem, I think you can use System Events and key code commands to navigate the context menu.

```
set mouseLoc to (do shell script "/usr/local/opt/MouseLocation")
set {astid, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ","}
tell mouseLoc to set {mouseX, mouseY} to {it's text item 1, it's text item 2}
set {mouseX, mouseY} to {(mouseX as integer), 1200 - (mouseY as integer)}

tell application "System Events"
    set frontProcessName to name of every process whose frontmost is true
    --  tell a to set aa to (get its name)
    set wnCount to count of windows of process named frontProcessName
    if wnCount > 0 then
        tell window 1 of process named frontProcessName
            set wnPos to its position
            set wnsize to its size
        end tell
        set {wnX, wnY, wnWidth, wnHeight} to {item 1 of wnPos, item 2 of wnPos, item 1 of wnsize, item 2 of wnsize}

        set {leftBound, RightBound, upperBound, lowerBound} to {wnX + 1, (wnX + wnWidth - 21), wnY + 50, (wnY + wnHeight - 51)}
        if mouseX ≥ leftBound and mouseX ≤ RightBound then
        else if mouseX < leftBound then
            set mouseX to leftBound
            log "a"
        else
            set mouseX to RightBound
            log "b"
        end if

        if mouseY ≥ upperBound and mouseY ≤ lowerBound then
        else if mouseY < upperBound then
            set mouseY to upperBound
            log "c"
        else
            set mouseY to lowerBound
            log "d"
        end if

    end if
end tell
set mouseLoc to "c" & mouseX & " " & mouseY
do shell script "/usr/local/opt/cliclick " & mouseLoc
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
```

Edit:

I didn't know that you couldn't find MouseLocation via Google anymore, I am sorry about that
If you have problems compiling the code found in post # 3 in this thread (http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=33468), then I recommend you use the MouseTool found here :(http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html)  instead, you would then need to change the first four lines of the script to something like:

```
set mouseLoc to (do shell script "MouseTools -location")
set {astid, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters,    return}
tell mouseLoc to set {mouseX, mouseY} to {it's text item 1, it's text item 2}
set {mouseX, mouseY} to {(mouseX as integer),(mouseY as integer)}
```

(You'll have to adjust the path to MouseTools as well as to cliclick.)

Comment: Hey thanks for answering; can you link to the MouseLocation tool? I've tried various Google searches such as MouseLocation shell script but Google returns nothing useful

Comment: Hello. I am sorry about MouseLocation not being found by google. I have provided a better alternative tool in my post. HTH

Comment: Hi McUser, thanks for your help. I'm getting this error: Can’t make " MouseTools" into type integer. I would paste my code in here, but it's too long; but I have followed your instructions.

Comment: Hello. Try executing this line in a separate script After you have prepended MouseTools with the path you use for MouseTools: log "" & (do shell script "which MouseTools")    Then. Look into the log in Applescript Editor. Either your path is wrong, or missing.

Comment: Hi, the error I'm getting is: error "Can’t make \" MouseTools\" into type integer." number -1700 from " MouseTools" to integer

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry you couldn't make it work. I am sure that if you add the path to where you installed Mousetools, to the second block of code, then you should have been able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171613/right-click-shortcut-for-mac-lion-os), it seems to be possible to do this within the system, using Universal Access.